# how we can apply fft to this file of(105,36)&read rows and store it into new array of(105,18)&plot a graph

Tags: python, numpy

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
        # get total number of rows

    print("Total no. of rows: %d" % (csvreader.line_num))

    print('\n rows are:\n')
    for row in rows[:csvreader.line_num]:
        # parsing each column of a row
        for col in row:
            print("%10s" % col),
            print('\n')


def read_rows():
    with open("u.dat") as textFile:
        rows = [[float(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in textFile]
    return np.array(rows)

rows = read_rows()
```

Comment: `rows` are undefined in your code

Comment: we just read the dat fileto csv file as rows

Comment: and thwe dimension is(105,36)

Comment: 1 array contains 36 values ,like 105 array is there

Comment: then you should define your method `read_rows()` and `rows` above line `with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:`

Comment: then how we can apply fft to it and store the positive values only(105,18) to an array

Comment: yes it is defined as# csv file name 
filename = r"C:\Users\sajin\Downloads\u.dat"
  
# initializing the titles and rows list 
rows = []